# Access parent value

Tags: php, attributes, parent

I have the following scenario:

```
class ClassA {
    protected $attr1 = 'value1';

    public function getAttr() {
        return $this->attr1;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    protected $attr1 = 'value2';

    public function getParentAttr() {
        return parent::getAttr();
    }
}

$object = new ClassB();
echo $object->getParentAttr(); //prints 'value2' instead of 'value1'
```

Is there a way to make `getParentAttr` return the default value of the parent's property, as its declared in `ClassA`?

I've tried to return `self::$attr1` in `getAttr` method but it throws an undeclared static property error.

Comment: You're overriding `$attr1` and asking why its not `value1`...

Comment: so, if i need to access its attribute with the parent value, Ill have to declare an new instance of ClassA?

Comment: `$attr1` is replaced in this case. You cannot access it.

Comment: No. you just doing it wrong and you do abuse polymorphism here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that by default and you should not in most cases. Anyway there are apparently two ways to achieve it.

**1. Using a new instance**

The easiest way is to create a new instance of the class and get the value from there. This might however have sideeffects and may not be possible in some cases.

**2. Using Reflection**

You can get the default values of a property using reflection.

```
$refl = new ReflectionClass("ClassA");
var_dump($refl->getDefaultProperties());
```

Which should result in:

```
array(1) {
    ["attr1"]=>
    string(6) "value1"
}
```